# reload `procmgr` in container?

Tags: php, docker, containers, buildpack

So I have a docker container build with buildpack that runs the following command under PID 1

```
procmgr /layers/paketo-buildpacks_php-web/php-web/procs.yml
```

is it possible to reload the configs passed into procmgr somehow?

```
  [DEV] backend-v1-7476cc6cfd-l68p2 app # 
ps aufx
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
cnb         30  1.0  0.0  18648  3444 pts/0    Ss   03:22   0:00 bash
cnb         77  0.0  0.0  34412  2944 pts/0    R+   03:22   0:00  \_ ps aufx
cnb          1  0.0  0.1 1013616 4096 ?        Ssl  03:20   0:00 procmgr /layers/paketo-buildpacks_php-web/php-web/procs.yml
cnb         24  0.0  0.7 323596 31260 ?        Ss   03:20   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/layers/paketo-buildpacks_php-web/php-web/etc/php-fpm.conf)
cnb         28  0.3  0.6 330252 24112 ?        S    03:20   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
cnb         29  0.1  0.6 330016 23900 ?        S    03:20   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
cnb         25  0.0  0.1  25132  5648 ?        S    03:20   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -p /workspace/app -c /workspace/app/nginx.conf
cnb         26  0.0  0.0  25132  1988 ?        S    03:20   0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
cnb         27  0.0  0.0  25132  1988 ?        S    03:20   0:00  \_ nginx: worker process

  [DEV] backend-v1-7476cc6cfd-l68p2 app # 
cat /layers/paketo-buildpacks_php-web/php-web/procs.yml
processes:
  nginx:
    command: nginx
    args:
    - -p
    - /workspace/app
    - -c
    - /workspace/app/nginx.conf
  php-fpm:
    command: php-fpm
    args:
    - -p
    - /layers/paketo-buildpacks_php-web/php-web
    - -y
    - /layers/paketo-buildpacks_php-web/php-web/etc/php-fpm.conf
    - -c
    - /layers/paketo-buildpacks_php-web/php-web/etc
```

Comment: The standard Docker approach I'd use is to stop, delete, and recreate the container.  If you ran the Nginx proxy and PHP application in separate containers, you'd only have to restart the one that had the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this, no. The `procmgr` cli that is used here is very basic.

https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/php-web/blob/main/cmd/procmgr/main.go

It loads the processes information listed in `procs.yml`, starts those processes, redirects all STDOUT/STDERR, and watches for a process to exit. If one process exits, then they all exit. There's no reload capability.

If you need to reload the information in `procs.yml`, you'll need to reload your container.